# Map a command that accepts an argument

Tags: command-line, key-bindings

I'm writing a Fortran parallel code using MPI.
I mapped `ctrl-C` to run `make`, in order to compile the program with proper options and dependencies. I also mapped `ctrl-<` to run the program executing the command `mpirun -np 8 program`, but this is limiting, since it runs the program on 8 processes. I would like to map the command so that I can press `ctrl-<` and then type `n enter` to run the program on `n` processes.

Comment: What range are you looking for for `n`? Will it ever be more than one-digit long?

Comment: Yes, it will be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function! Mpirn()
  let n = nr2char(getchar())
  exe "!mpirun -np ".n." program"
endfunction

nnoremap <C-c> :<C-u>call Mpirn()<cr>
```

(Note, I had trouble mapping to `<C-<>` so I left it mapped to `<C-c>` You can change this to whatever mapping you already have.)

Pretty straightforward answer. Takes a single number as input, and runs that command. If you ever need to run this with a two digit or more number, you can do this instead:

```
function! MpirnArg(n)
  exe "!mpirun -np ".a:n." program"
endfunction

nnoremap <C-c> :<C-u>call MpirnArg(v:count)<cr>
```

However, the way you call this is in reverse. e.g, `17<C-c>` Rather than `<C-c>17`

Also, I'm not familiar with fortran or MPI, so I don't know if `0` is valid. If `0` is *not* valid, change that last mapping to this:

```
nnoremap <C-c> :<C-u>call MpirnArg(v:count1)<cr>
```

Otherwise, you can leave it the same.

Comment: I come back to this question to ask for an explanation on a particular: why is `<C-u>` needed here?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I personally have never run into issues while *not* using `<C-u>`. It's just kindof a "best practice" that I have learned and try to stick to. Essentially, it clears the command line before running, just in case vim inserts `:'<,'>` or something else. A better explanation is found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830874/onoremap-vim-c-u-purpose)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `v:count`. You can use this in your mapping to see what number was entered before the mapping was pressed. From `:h v:count`:

> :map _x :echo "the count is " . v:count